# Replacing probability distributions by degenerate ones

Tags: probability, integration, analysis

Let $f: [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow \Delta^{n-1}$ be a mapping that maps the unit square into the $n-1$ dimensional probability simplex. Thus, for every $(x_1, x_2) \in [0, 1]^2$, $f(x_1,x_2)$ is a probability distribution over $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Define $F_1: [0, 1] \rightarrow \Delta^{n-1}$ as
$$F_1(x_1) = \int_0^1 f(x_1, x_2) \mathrm{d}x_2, \quad \forall x_1 \in [0, 1].$$
Similarly, define $F_2: [0, 1] \rightarrow \Delta^{n-1}$ as
$$F_2(x_2) = \int_0^1 f(x_1, x_2) \mathrm{d} x_1, \quad \forall x_2 \in [0, 1].$$ Does there exist $h: [0, 1]^2 \rightarrow \Delta^{n-1}$ such that (i) for every $(x_1, x_2)$, $h(x_1, x_2)$ is degenerate, i.e., $h(x_1, x_2)$ puts probability one on one element in $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, and both $H_1 = F_1$ and $H_2 = F_2$ hold, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are similarly defined from $h$ as $F_1$, $F_2$ from $f$:
$$ H_1(x_1) = \int_0^1 h(x_1, x_2) \mathrm{d}x_2 \text{ and } H_2(x_2) = \int_0^1 h(x_1, x_2) \mathrm{d} x_1.$$

If we only require $H_1 = F_1$ or $H_2 = F_2$, the answer is positive but easy. We can construct
$h(x_1, x_2) = \delta_k$ if $x_2 \in (\sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} F_{1j}(x_1), \sum_{j = 0}^{k}F_{1j}(x_1))$, where $\delta_k$ is the degenerate probability that puts probability one on $k$, and $F_{10} = 0$. But I have no idea how to proceed with both $H_1 = F_1$ and $H_2 = F_2$ requirements. If in general it is not possible, then is it possible if the ranges of $F_1$ and $F_2$ are both finite.

Perhaps the title is not appropriate. But I can not come up with a better one. Thank you very much for any help or reference.

Comment: A very interesting question! For $n=2$, the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of $h$ is given in the [article of Lorentz](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372255). No idea what happens for $n>2$, but this might be answered in the literature, just look the papers citing Lorentz.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you so much for the reference. I did not even know what key words to search! Did not expect this to be a difficult problem:(

Comment: You're most welcome! What's the motivation by the way?

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks! Think about $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two independent and uniformly distributed random variable. A system $f$ determines, for each $(x_1, x_2)$, a randomization over $n$ alternatives. $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the conditional distribution over these $n$ alternatives given $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. I am just wondering whether the randomized $f$ can be replaced by a deterministic one without changing the conditional distributions.